# eli5 show_prediction not showing probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm using the `show_prediction` function in the `eli5` package to understand how my XGBoost classifier arrived at a prediction. For some reason I seem to be getting a regression score instead of a probability for my model.

Below is a fully reproducible example with a public dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from eli5 import show_prediction

# Load dataset
data = load_breast_cancer()

# Organize our data
label_names = data['target_names']
labels = data['target']
feature_names = data['feature_names']
features = data['data']


# Split the data
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(
    features,
    labels,
    test_size=0.33,
    random_state=42
)

# Define the model
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(
    n_jobs=16,
    eval_metric='auc'
)

# Train the model
xgb_model.fit(
    train,
    train_labels
)

show_prediction(xgb_model.get_booster(), test[0], show_feature_values=True, feature_names=feature_names)
```

This gives me the following result. Note the score of 3.7, which is definitely not a probability.

[image]

The official eli5 [documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/xgboost-titanic.html#explaining-predictions) correctly shows a probability though.

[image]

The missing probability seems to be related to my use of `xgb_model.get_booster()`. Looks like the official documentation doesn't use that and passes the model as-is instead, but when I do that I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`, so that doesn't seem to be an option.

I'm also concerned that eli5 is not explaining the prediction by traversing the xgboost trees. It appears that the "score" I'm getting is actually just a sum of all the feature contributions, like I would expect if eli5 wasn't actually traversing the tree but fitting a linear model instead. Is that true? How can I also make eli5 traverse the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my own problem. According to [this Github Issue](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/issues/252) eli5 only supports an older version of XGBoost (<=0.6). I was using XGBoost version 0.80 and eli5 version 0.8.

Posting the solution from the issue:

```
import eli5
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, XGBRegressor

def _check_booster_args(xgb, is_regression=None):
    # type: (Any, bool) -> Tuple[Booster, bool]
    if isinstance(xgb, eli5.xgboost.Booster): # patch (from "xgb, Booster")
        booster = xgb
    else:
        booster = xgb.get_booster() # patch (from "xgb.booster()" where `booster` is now a string)
        _is_regression = isinstance(xgb, XGBRegressor)
        if is_regression is not None and is_regression != _is_regression:
            raise ValueError(
                'Inconsistent is_regression={} passed. '
                'You don\'t have to pass it when using scikit-learn API'
                .format(is_regression))
        is_regression = _is_regression
    return booster, is_regression

eli5.xgboost._check_booster_args = _check_booster_args
```

And then replacing the last line of my question's code snippet with:

```
show_prediction(xgb_model, test[0], show_feature_values=True, feature_names=feature_names)
```

fixed my problem.